# Should "Warren Buffett is quoted as saying" have the word "is" there?

Tags: past-participles

When I was reading a book I notice something weird to me:

> Warren Buffett is quoted as saying,

Why the author use "is" after that the verb "quoted" with the past participle?
I think the "is" wrong he should write the sentence without "is" because the "is" in past participle:

> Warren Buffett quoted as saying.

Comment: *BE* + past participle expresses the passive voice.

Comment: Also note that the sentence would lack a main verb if you removed *is*. (Verbs in the cited quotation, implied in your question, don't count.)

Answer (score 2):

This is passive, Warren Buffet didn't quote: Warren Buffet is being quoted (currently and passively, by someone else) as saying something.